# journald forwarding to syslog seems to be lagged

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, ubuntu-16.04, syslog, journald

I'm seeing an issue on a Ubuntu 16.04 box where the copying/forwarding of journal messages to /var/log/syslog seems to be delayed:

```
theuser@host:/etc/systemd$ sudo journalctl -n 1 && sudo tail -n 1 /var/log/syslog

-- Logs begin at Wed 2018-12-12 09:52:03 CST, end at Fri 2018-12-14 08:41:20 CST. --

Dec 14 08:41:20 host sudo[26760]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by theuser(uid=0)
Dec 14 07:40:12 host sudo[2574]: *log message snipped*
```

I've confirmed that `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` has not set `ForwardToSyslog=no` (the default value of yes is *presumably* being used).

The problem appears sporadically, and usually seems to be resolved by rebooting, but I was hoping to maybe get some suggestions on what I should check into / what might be causing this so I could poke around on a system currently experiencing the issue.

One other piece of probably-relevant information is that I'm using rsyslog to forward logs from `/var/log/syslog` to an external log aggregation service.

Any tips on what I should check into?

Comment: I can't tell from from the example how long the lag is. Are you talking about seconds, minutes, hours or days?

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clearer. At the point I took those logs, the latest journald entry was from 8:41:20, while the latest syslog entry was from 7:40:12, so the lag is about an hour.